# Hosting asp.net core 2.2 app on IIS gives an error 500

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-hosting

I have installed an application developed in **asp.net core 2.2** on Hosting provider's IIS.
On running the application from the browser, it gives an error 500 Internal server error without any other details.

Running the application with hosting provider's **cmd dotnet appname runs successfully** without any error.

No error is stored in logs directory inspite of
stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" in web.config

**Hosting bundle of asp.net core 2.2.8 has been installed**. 
IIS is configured with application pool as No Managed Code.
But error persists (without details) with 
***500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.***

I must be skipping some steps. Kindly help.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could consider using fail request tracing to see what has happened when throw the 500 error. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: Thanks @Brando Zhang. I am going to follow the steps mentioned in the article and post the findings.

Comment: Edit your question to include the diagnostics report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and then others can see how you configured the server and the application.